# Force click without an apple trackpad?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, trackpad, multi-touch

On a macbook, we can use force click on trackpad to loop up words or do some other things.

However, an "ordinary" mouse does not have the hardware for force click.

How can we trigger force click without using the trackpad? For instance, something like command + click, or using AppleScript.

Comment: Interesting thought. Force touch is the haptic feedback to alert us that  the multi touch hardware has generated one of the dozens of detections it watches for. If there’s a public  SDK to generate those events, it’s likely this will be something a third party app could provide or possible be scriptable on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything you can do with a Force click can be done by selecting something in the Contextual menu (right-click, or CTRL-click).

[image]